# Azure Data Factory - Remove duplicate rows and only remain one unique row

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

within Azure Data Factory I have a table with 2 columns. I want to remove all duplicate rows and only remain one distinct row.

Currently:

```
columnA, columnB
a1,b1
a1,b1
a2,b2
a3,b3
a3,b3
a3,b4
```

After the transformation:

```
columnA, columnB
a1,b1    
a2,b2
a3,b3
a3,b4
```

What I did so far: I created a data flow where I use aggregate flow, I then group by columnA and tried to build an expression pattern that kills every non-distinctive row.
But it doesnt work :/  It seems that having to check the "distinctness" on both columns is not easy done. Any ideas? :/

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below approach to achieve your requirement. But note that this **approach won't preserve the rows order in the target as same it is in the source**.

First use `sha2(256,columns())` in the **aggregate transformation group by** and give any name to this column.

[image]

Now, in the aggregates section, use `first($$)`in it like below.

[image]

It will give the distinct rows like below with the extra column `columns`.

[image]

Use **Rule based mapping** in the **select transformation** to remove the extra column.

[image]

Now, it will give the desired result:

[image]